# GWTP Reveal & placemanager

Tags: gwtp

Can I explain in more detail what is the difference between and revealPlace
revealRelativePlace

Just in case the first placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest () is cleared , and the second no

http://javadoc.gwt-platform.googlecode.com/hg/0.5/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/proxy/PlaceManager.html

Answer (score 3):

From the JavaDoc :(http://arcbees.github.io/GWTP/javadoc/apidocs/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/proxy/PlaceManager.html#revealPlace(com.gwtplatform.mvp.shared.proxy.PlaceRequest) :

```
void revealRelativePlace(PlaceRequest request)
```

> This discards the current place hierarchy, effectively revealing the request as a top-level place.
>
> To keep the current place hierarchy, see revealRelativePlace(PlaceRequest), revealRelativePlace(PlaceRequest, int) or revealRelativePlace(int).

So, `revealRelativePlace` essentially keeps the current hierarchy of places, where `revealPlace` does not.